# How do I prevent html element from escaping parent? (security)

Tags: javascript, html, security

I tried to Google this, but everything is related to css, not security.

I have this as a comment form:

```
<pre name="comment">
    <comment-content>
        This is a sample comment by a user
    </comment-content>
</pre>
```

I allowed some controlled html tags that include `[pre][/pre]` and this is where the problem starts.

if I do something like this:

```
<pre name="comment">
    <comment-content>
        This is a sample comment by a user
        [/pre]
        This text will be outside the comment container
    </comment-content>
</pre>
```

The comment escapes the pre tag, and ignores that its inside the `<comment-content></comment-content>` tag. I added this tag as an attempt to block escaping, but it doesn't work. I also notice my controlled html tags will run outside the container. I have a second container that is not escaped, but this issue with escaping the first container means if I put a `<pre>` tag outside that container, it could be escaped. I also tried doubling up the container, but that did not work either.

[Here is an image of the [/pre] tag escaping the container](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMfoN.png)

here is a quick sample of what javascript is doing in the background:

```
//I added .cleanHTML() as a similar function to php htmlentities() and .clean() is similar to php strip_tags()
let content = $(this).html().cleanHTML().clean();

commentHtml += '<pre name="comment" type="text/plain"><comment-content>'+setUserCommentHtml(content.clean())+'</comment-content></pre>';

$(this).html(commentHtml);
```

Note: I am aware that most security should be done server side, but would also like to keep client side secure as well.

I basically need a way to force html to require the first closing tag before the second parents closing tag will work.

Comment: Validate your tag scheme before parsing it. If it fails, treat it all as text (e.g., `textContent`) and don't parse it.

Comment: "Validate your tag scheme", that sounds like a good solution. Inside the `setUserCommentHtml()` function, if I push to an array, every time the user opens a tag, then verify the opened tag before closing it, and removing from that list, that seems to work.

Comment: I think it's simple enough to resolve if you [did it a little differently](https://jsfiddle.net/y9rpmb4c/). Create dom element nodes for your `pre` and `comment-content` elements and append the comment content into that. It'll cleanup your stray `</pre>` tag and other "quirky" html misbehaviors.

Comment: Yes, also validate the tags you're using too. There should be some good Javascript bbcode libraries out there.

Comment: for tag validation I have it require the tag existing in a const jsonList

`const customUserAllowedHtml = {
  "userTag": ["htmlTag", "userParam1=validHtmlParam1", "userParam2=validHtmlParam2", "userParam3=validHtmlParam3"],
}`

if a parameter is not in this list, it gets striped out. It's basically fake html a user can use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting solutions (with help from comments) as an answer to mark as solved.

Jared Farrish answered question in comments.

changing my javascript to something like this fixes the issue:

```
//I added .cleanHTML() as a similar function to php htmlentities() and .clean() is similar to php strip_tags()
let content = $(this).html().cleanHTML().clean();

let setContentId = Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);
commentHtml += '<pre name="comment" type="text/plain"><comment-content set-content="'+setContentId+'"></comment-content></pre>';

$(this).html(commentHtml);

$('comment-content[set-content="'+setContentId+'"]').html(setUserCommentHtml(content.clean()));
```

I also added this method Inside the `setUserCommentHtml()` function.

```
let htmlOpenTags = [];

//in a loop
if(tagType === 'close' && htmlOpenTags.includes(commentTag)){
    htmlOpenTags.splice(htmlOpenTags.lastIndexOf(commentTag));
    //close tag here
    ...
}else if(tagType === 'open'){
    htmlOpenTags.push(commentTag);
    //open tag here
    ...
}
```

If I push to an array, every time the user opens a tag, Then I can verify the opened tag exists in that array before closing it and remove that tag from the list.

edit: stack overflow says I must wait 2 days before marking as answer